# I want a bar type display for my Arduino Project

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, display, tft, oled

I am trying to make a smart table project. But I have stumbled upon one problem, that is I don't know which display should I use. I need a display that has roughly aspect ratio of 2:1 but also has a relatively high pixel density. I have purchased a 2.42 inch display based on SSD1309 but the display is way too pixelated for my use. Do you have any display recommendations for me?

This is the display that I have bought:

[image: 2.42" Inch 12864 128 * 64 OLED Display Module IIC I2C SPI Serial White/Blue/Green/Yellow LCD Screen for C51 STM32 SSD1309]

The display I am trying to achieve is like this:

[image]

It looked like the display that I'm trying to achieve uses a custom made display. Is there anyway I can achieve that kind of look (at least similar in quality) with displays on the market?

Comment: Yes, that is a custom display. No, not without a really high res screen, and those are really expensive and hard to drive from an Arduino. You could always use a mobile phone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Majenko already stated, the second image shows a custom display. It is not pixelated, because each shown element/symbol has it's own element in the LCD. When you have one of these displays, you might be able to reuse it for your project, but that is advanced.

In the case of pixel based displays with a significantly higher resolution than the standard SSD1309 driven LCD or OLED displays, you are mostly out of luck. There might be fitting products, though they most likely will be expensive and are not as easy to drive, as the standard ones. AVR based Arduinos, like Uno, Nano or Mega, are also not really good for driving high res displays.

The way to go depends on your exact requirements.

- You could - as Majenko suggested - ditch the Arduino and use an old smartphone. If you need more control over the smartphone for your project, than the standard Andriod gives you, you could install an open source OS on the phone.
- You could move to a Single Board Computer, like the Raspberry Pi Zero, and buy a display for it. There are many displays for Raspberry Pis, that should have enough resolution. Though most of them are larger than a normal smartphone display.